# How to register a function in a driver code as its ISR

Tags: linux-device-driver, irq, isr, registering

Following the feedback i got from [my previous question on Linux Kernel development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683682/new-to-linux-kernel-driver-development/2683819),

I have written a driver (in Linux-kernel v2.6.32) by comparing it with an existing driver and "borrowing" heavily from its code. The driver is registered fine. The init() and probe() are working fine. I am also able to access the peripheral device registers. **:-)**

However i am a bit hazy about the **IRQ/ISR**. The peripheral-device is a input device and raises an interrupt on a GPIO pin.

> How do i move ahead from the current state to handle the IRQ and execute my ISR function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the [**Linux Device Drivers**](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) book? It has a **[whole chapter on interrupt handling](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch10.pdf)**. It should provide the background information you need.